# Clip div also clip the scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs whitch the div child is inside of the div parent. The div child is bigger that his parent. So I decide to put a scroll in the div parent for i can see better the content of the div child.

The problem is that now I need to use the property clip in the parent div, but the clip also affects the scroll.

What I would like to ask if there is any way that I could clip the parent div and the scroll size ajdustes automaclty to the scroll.

Follows my code:

```css
.outter{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(23.75px 120px 120px 23.75px);
}

.inner{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

[EDIT]:

Follows thee result that i pretend.

[image]

If you campare the image above and the result of the snippet that I put above is that in the result the scrolls apears cut and the image is not

Comment: Usually we call it child and parent div... not son and father

Comment: Thank you @k97513. I already made the change :)

Comment: I don't understand what result you want.  Could post an image of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @BuhBuh I made chages to the post. I hope know it is more clear to you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by clipping? Are you trying to restrict part of what is shown by the inner div? For example, if that inner div contains an image with two people in it, one on left and one on right, you want to clip the left person out, but allow the user to scroll around the right side of the image?

Comment: @RicardoRocha Did my answer below help? Or is there a reason you want to use clip instead?

Answer (score 0):

That is what the `clip` property is supposed to do, restrict the visible area of an element. If you are trying to clip the contents of the inner element, you can absolutely position it to do so.

Hope this helps!

```css
.outter {
    position: relative; 
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    background-color:red;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.inner{
    position: absolute;
    left: -40px;
    top: -40px;
    background:url('http://placekitten.com/g/400/400');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm working on a big webapp. Part of the code is already implemented and I cannot change sometimes the way that I want. The solution that you gave me I already had though about but i came to conclusion that is not work for me. But thank you for try to help me.